# Swift - WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript выдаёт ошибку при вызове

Tags: javascript, swift, webkit

Есть у меня WKWebView, в переменной webView. Все работает, за исключением одного - при попытке сделать evaluateJavaScript, происходит такая ошибка. Как решить, не подскажете, пожалуйста?
[image: Ошибка]

***UPD:***

Вот инициализация webView:
[image: Инициализация]

Вот extension к ViewController, где происходит обработка и evaluate:
[image: Extension]

В выводе nil - следовательно, ошибка. Но почему же nil?

Comment: Похоже, webView не инициализирован. Если он сделан через аутлет, то проверьте, что связь установлена.

Comment: @Oleg Soloviev WebView сделан не через аутлет. При загрузке View он инициализируется. Сам evaluatejavascript происходит по сигналу из JS (в WebView). Ошибка скорее всего действительно в том, что переменная nil, но почему же? Может, потому что вызов происходит в extension для ViewController? (Я новичок в Swift)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, где инициализируются webView.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, Добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо let webView = ... напишите просто webView = ..., иначе вы создаете новую webView, а не присваиваете инициализированное значение.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил.